# Why does Entity Framework Core require "top 200" for ContainsTable() order by?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

In SSMS the following query works fine, returning the expected 1 row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(AppUsers, *, 'hick', 200) AS t 
INNER JOIN AppUsers u ON u.Id = t.[KEY] 
ORDER BY t.[RANK] DESC
```

But when I call the following using Entity Framework, the exact same select:

```
listUsers = await dbContext.AppUsers.FromSqlInterpolated(
        $@"SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(AppUsers, *, {Query}, 200) as t INNER JOIN AppUsers u on u.Id = t.[KEY] ORDER BY t.[RANK] desc")
        .ToListAsync();
```

I get an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'LouisHowe.core.Data.NoTrackingDbContext'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__208_0(Task`1 result)   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
>
> ClientConnectionId:34a279b8-9257-4414-b7d0-b0a3c135a4db
> Error Number:1033,State:1,Class:15

Now this works:

```
listUsers = await dbContext.AppUsers.FromSqlInterpolated(
        $@"SELECT top 200 * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(AppUsers, *, {Query}, 200) as t INNER JOIN AppUsers u on u.Id = t.[KEY] ORDER BY t.[RANK]")
        .ToListAsync();
```

But why do I have to add `top 200` as I'm passing the `200` in to `CONTAINSTABLE()`?

Comment: EF probably wraps your select in some subselect, where order by isn't allowed, trace the actual query being send to the server

Comment: @siggemannen turned out to be even more basic than that - Entity Framework requires it.

Comment: ORM's like EF keep me in work!

Comment: @MitchWheat EF gives me grey hair :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The answer is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries):

> Composing with LINQ requires your SQL query to be composable, since EF
> Core will treat the supplied SQL as a subquery. Composable SQL queries
> generally begin with the SELECT keyword, and cannot contain SQL
> features that aren't valid in a subquery, such as:
>
> - On SQL Server, an ORDER BY clause that isn't used with OFFSET 0 OR TOP 100 PERCENT in the SELECT clause

Comment: you link didn't work :/

Comment: @siggemannen - sorry, fixed